# Apached Web Traffic Routing to backend applications

Tags: apache

I wanted to know if it is possible to do web routing in apache like you can in IIS?

```
Example:
Internet -> web-server:80/443 -> ajax:8181
Internet -> web-server:80/443 -> media:8443
```

With IIS you can have an IIS router that handles web traffic in front of applications and they may be in a different zone not accessible to the internet unless through the router. Can you do the same thing with Apache?

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of word manipulation, I was able to find what I was looking for. It's called a reverse proxy.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html